# Handle multiple duplicate key error in mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

I'm trying to get from document.save() all the duplicate key errors, the schema declares a username and email unique, at the moment of handling duplicate key errors, i just get the first one, not the two of them.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser>(
  {
    userName:{
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max:20,
      unique: true,
    },
    email:{
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 50,
      unique: true,
    },
  },{timestamps:true}
)
```

and here is where the error occurs :

```
const newUser = new User({
      userName
      email,
    })
    const savedUser = await newUser.save()
```

but, just the first duplicate error gets caught,
is there a way in which, save return both errors and not just the first caught.